# Redirecting to original (unauthenticated page) after spring security openid authentication

Tags: spring-security, openid

I have implemented spring security openid integration using the sample available here:[OpenId+Spring Integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/sample-apps.html)

The integration works fine. When I request a protected resource I get redirected to a login page and after authentication I'm automagically redirected to the protected resource.

However, if I am on an unprotected page ( similar to the situation described here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?95317-Redirect-to-original-page-after-login-success-failure ) and I click on the login button..I get redirected to the homepage after login. I would like to be redirected to the page where I clicked the login button from.

The spring forum thread suggests overriding the buildReturnToUrl method. I have debugged thru it. It always generates a returnToURL of the form:

```
http://localhost:8080/listocal/j_spring_openid_security_check
```

There was some behind the scene communication between op and Rob Winch and I'm not sure how op actually overwrote it.

Alternatively, I have tried to create another filter with code like this:

```
public void doFilter(....) {
...
DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest((HttpServletRequest) request, new PortResolverImpl());

((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST", savedRequest);

}
```

If this filter runs before the OpenIDAuthenticationFilter then the savedrequest is removed by RequestCacheAwareFilter ( probably because of this issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1241)

If this filter runs after OpenIDAuthenticationFilter then I do run into the issue where post parameters get concatenated after each request.

Can someone point out the right way forward on this?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered by the spring-security team on the spring forums. See this:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?128480-Redirecting-to-original-(unauthenticated-page)-after-spring-security-openid-authentic

Comment: Prashant do you have any demo for this?